# Invoke Causes Memory Leak

Tags: .net, multithreading, winforms, memory-leaks

First, the background, I'm attempting to do a cross-thread update when a System.Timer fires. Due to the nature of the code, using a SynchronizatoinContext on the timer is not a solution. I found that this pattern was convenient for the cross-thread update

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
..lots of form update code here...
});
```

However, it appears to be creating **new threads each call which aren't being garbage collected causing a memory/thread leak**.

I've search stack overflow for answers and found conflicting information. Some threads such as this one [BeginInvoke Memory Leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125008/begininvoke-memory-leak) claim that EndInvoke is needed where others claim that it isn't needed.

My question is exactly what is happening, and how can I fix it?

Update:
Below is the pseudo code for how this works

```
 Main Form
    System.Timer -> Fires -> Calls UpdateForm() On Secondary Form

    Secondary Form

    UpdateForm()
    {
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
   ..lots of form update code here for multiple controls..
    });
    }
```

The program is leaking memory and my hypothesis is that the leak is caused by infinite creation of threads.

Comment: Do you have a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Note that the thread you've linked to is about calling `BeginInvoke` on a delegate, rather than on a form.

Comment: Also, are you sure the memory is leeking and not that the garbage collector decided its not time to do a full collection yet (or you are running inside a debugger which prevents objects from being garbage collected if they are still in scope)

Comment: The question says that it's about `BeginInvoke`, but your code is calling `Invoke`. If you're calling `Invoke`, then all the discussion of `BeginInvoke` is irrelevant. Also, what makes you think you have a memory leak? Finally, if your timer ticks again before your update is finished, you'll have reentrancy problems. All told, your question is unclear and you haven't given us enough information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: `Control.BeginInvoke` does **not** require and `EndInvoke`. This is different from `Delegate.BeginInvoke` which needs a matching `Delegate.EndInvoke`.

Comment: You might be flooding the message queue.  What is the Timer interval?...and how long does it take to complete `..lots of form update code here...`?

Comment: With a little bit of effort you can investigate the issue yourself and avoid the speculations. This article may be a good start: http://alexatnet.com/articles/net-memory-management-and-garbage-collector So what you needed to do is to start you app, attach the debugger and perform a few commands to get info about the memory usage.